# How can I get an i2c touch device work on linux?

Tags: linux, touch, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am using a touch screen which has gt9271. It is connected via i2c.

###### Whats wrong

It just dont show up in `/dev/input`. There is only a `event0`, which is the keyboard according to what dmesg shows. Document says it should show up as `event1`, but it did not.

###### Envirounment

It is a STM32MP157 board runnning Debian Stretch based linux, from the manufacture.
`uname -a` shows `Linux PanGuBoard 4.19.43 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 22 17:02:06 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

###### What did I check

I saw its driver in linux kernel 4.19 source.
I decompiled my dtb file and confirmed it is configured.
I also checked `dmesg` and found nothing about gt9271 in it.

Since it is a STM32MP157 board, I tried the system based on stlinux which is also from the manufacture.
The `/dev/input/event1` shows up and works fine. dmesg shows its discovery too.

Any advice what I should do or did I miss something important?

Comment: We are now in v5.14 cycle, try better kernel.

Comment: Updating kernel on a manufacture costumed system sounds like it may lead to more problems. Anyway I will have a try since I dont know what to do now.

Comment: Good luck then! At least bugs should be reported against upstream and not some antique kernels. Anyway, since you are using Debian, report bug there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I recompiled linux kernel and its modules with the code given by manufacture, and the problem solved.
It turns out that they give me the wrong kernel image which has neither goodix driver compiled nor module support.